# How do I prove that 4 is even using Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Assuming that I have this inductive definition for Even

```
inductive_set Even :: "Int.int set"
  where null: "0 ∈ Even"
  | plus: "x ∈ Even ⟹ x+2 ∈ Even" 
  | min: "x ∈ Even ⟹ x-2 ∈ Even"
```

How do I prove this lemma
`lemma four_is_even: "4 ∈ Even"` ?

I am relatively new to proof assistant.

Comment: In forward manner: like you would do by hand: 0 is even, hence 0+2 is even, hence (0+2)+2 is even. So 4 is even. If you want to do it backwards: 4 is even <--> (4-2)+2 is even. To prove that, it is sufficient to prove that ((4-2) - 2) is even. The backwards version is slightly ugly in Isabelle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mathias Fleury informally explained above, there are several ways in which you can prove your lemma:

**Using forward-style reasoning**

You can first prove the following auxiliary lemma using the `OF` fact combinator:

```
lemma four_is_even_fwd': "0+2+2 ∈ Even"
  by (fact plus [OF plus [OF null]])
```

and then let the simplifier take care of proving 0+2+2 = 4:

```
lemma four_is_even_fwd: "4 ∈ Even"
  using four_is_even_fwd' by simp
```

Also, you can use the Isabelle/Isar proof language to produce a more structured and pedagogical proof:

```
lemma four_is_even_fwd_str: "4 ∈ Even"
proof -
  have "0 ∈ Even"
    by (fact null)
  then have "0+2 ∈ Even"
    by (fact plus)
  then have "0+2+2 ∈ Even"
    by (fact plus)
  then show ?thesis
    by simp
qed
```

**Using backward-style reasoning**

Similarly to the first example of the forward-style reasoning above, you can prove the following auxiliary lemma using `apply`-scripts:

```
lemma four_is_even_bwd': "0+2+2 ∈ Even"
  apply (rule plus) (* subgoal: 0+2 ∈ Even *)
  apply (rule plus) (* subgoal: 0 ∈ Even *)
  apply (rule null) (* no subgoals! *)
  done
```

and then again let the simplifier take care of proving 0+2+2 = 4:

```
lemma four_is_even_bwd: "4 ∈ Even"
  using four_is_even_bwd' by simp
```

Of course, trying to prove your lemma using `Even.min` is much more involved.